# Convert $date from advanced custom fields in wordpress to php format

Tags: php, wordpress, datetime

I have a advanced custom field time and date picker setup in my admin section in wordpress, when I run my code below I get the following error `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (1527053460)` I am using [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/acf-field-date-time-picker/#description) plugin for advanced custom fields

This is the code I have tried

```
<?php 
    // get raw date
    $date = get_field('event_date', false, false);
    echo $date;
    // make date object
    $date = new DateTime($date);
?>

<p><?php echo $date->format('jS F'); ?></p>
<p><?php echo $date->format('D,\ F jS,\ o gi'); ?></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a Unix timestamp you must tell DateTime it is one by prepending the `@` symbol before the value:

```
<?php 
    // get raw date
    $date = get_field('event_date', false, false);
    echo $date;
    // make date object
    $date = new DateTime('@'.$date);
?>

<p><?php echo $date->format('jS F'); ?></p>
<p><?php echo $date->format('D,\ F jS,\ o gi'); ?></p>
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/1012207)

Comment: Your answer is much better, completely forgot about the using `@`. +1.

Comment: It would be nice if PHP was smart enough to auto-detect it. Then it would be no different than any other valid datetime value.